# If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $a\in (0,1)$, the rational derivative of $f$ at $a: \lim_{\Bbb Q\ni r_n\to a}\frac{f(a+r_n)-f(a)}{r_n}=A$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

> If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $a\in (0,1)$, the rational derivative of $f$ at $a: \lim\limits_{\Bbb Q\ni r_n\to0}\frac{f(a+r_n)-f(a)}{r_n}=A$.
> Show $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

***My attempt:***

For any $x_n\searrow 0$, find $0<r_n<x_n<s_n$ such that $s_n\to 0$. But

$\dfrac{f(a+r_n)-f(a)}{r_n}, \dfrac{f(a+x_n)-f(a)}{x_n}, \dfrac{f(a+s_n)-f(a)}{s_n}$

is not compatible. How to use the continuity ?

Comment: $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$

Comment: @Will But we have to divide $x_n\searrow 0$, would you please give more hint?

Comment: In fact it is not necessary to speak about uniform continuity. Just take $r_n$ such that $r_n-x_n\to0$ and $\vert f(a+r_n)-f(a+x_n)\vert\le\frac{x_n}{n}$. Then use that $\frac{f(a+x_n)-f(a)}{x_n}=\frac{f(a+r_n)-f(a)}{r_n}\frac{r_n}{x_n}+\frac{f(a+x_n)-f(a+r_n)}{x_n}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $r_n \to 0$ instead of $r_n \to a$?